# How to make 7 days xAxes label and plot 1000 datas into it?

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js

I have around 1000 datas from my research that i have stored in database Mysql. I already import the datas into a variable called dataTeg1, i import it with json_encode. 1 data include a value, date, time, and so on. I want to plot it to my website using Chart.js. How to make 7 days xAxes label properly? and how to store 1000 datas into that 7 days?

this is what i have got, and this is still wrong
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOFS7.jpg

```
var config = {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: [newDate(-3), newDate(-2), newDate(-1), newDate(0), newDate(1), newDate(2), newDate(3)],
        datasets: [{
            label: "Value",
            data: dataTeg1,
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'time',
                unit: 'day',
                unitStepSize: 1,
                time: {
                    displayFormats: {
                        'millisecond': 'MMM DD',
                        'second': 'MMM DD',
                        'minute': 'MMM DD',
                        'hour': 'MMM DD',
                        'day': 'MMM DD',
                        'week': 'MMM DD',
                        'month': 'MMM DD',
                        'quarter': 'MMM DD',
                        'year': 'MMM DD',
                    }
                }
            }],
        },
    }
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
new Chart(ctx, config);
```